# How to aggregate and filter mongodb collections correctly in node (mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a collection of motorcycles in my MongoDB database. Each motorcycle (collection) has an array of `units` and each unit has an array of `parts` with the name and SKU number. I'm trying to fetch only those units which contain given SKU number (in this example `PT00002`).

I tried to use aggregation, project and filter, but every time I get empty array of `units`:

```
let responseData = await Model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    'units.parts.SKU': sku,
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    'units': {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$units',
                            as: 'unit',
                            cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                    '$$unit.parts.SKU', sku
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Documents look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6351183b841ef5ca0e090482'),
    name: 'Yamaha Tenere 2022',
    units: [
        {
            name: 'Front wheel',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00001',
                    name: 'Bolt m7'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Rear wheel',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00003',
                    name: 'Bolt m7'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6351183b841ef5ca0e090483'),
    name: 'Yamaha Tenere 2021',
    units: [
        {
            name: 'Exhaust system',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00012',
                    name: 'Screw torx'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Suspension',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'GGG02',
                    name: 'Front fork'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'GGG02',
                    name: 'Rear fork'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output (for SKU `PT00002` ) should be like this (no "Suspension unit" in array):

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6351183b841ef5ca0e090482'),
    name: 'Yamaha Tenere 2022',
    units: [
        {
            name: 'Front wheel',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00001',
                    name: 'Bolt m7'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Rear wheel',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00003',
                    name: 'Bolt m7'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('6351183b841ef5ca0e090483'),
    name: 'Yamaha Tenere 2021',
    units: [
        {
            name: 'Exhaust system',
            parts: [
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00012',
                    name: 'Screw torx'
                },
                {
                    SKU: 'PT00002',
                    name: 'Oring'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had small error with my aggregate query. The one below works:

```
        let responseData = await Model.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    'units.parts.SKU': sku,
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    'name': 1,
                    'year': 1,
                    'code': 1,
                    'category': 1,
                    'units': {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$units',
                            as: 'unit',
                            cond: {
                                $in: [
                                    sku, '$$unit.parts.SKU'
                                ],
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```